# C++ Dynamic Inventory System--Adding/Removing Items

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, dynamic, inventory

Ok, so I have a text-driven game in C++. I've written a Hero class. I also wrote a base class called Item and a subclass of that called Weapon (the idea is to have Weapons, Potions, QuestItems, etc. that inherit from the Item class). That way I can make my "Hero" have an instance variable inventory of Items. I wanted this to be dynamic in case the Hero gained upgrades for his/her storage space.

So my Hero class has a member/instance variable that is a dynamic array of pointers to Items. I declare this and then loop through it setting each element to a new Item like so:

```
Item** inventory = new Item*[15];
for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++)
    inventory[i] = new Item();
```

That took place in the Hero class's void Init() function which all the constructors call (flexible construction). Now then, I have tried to write a member function to add an item to the first "empty" slot in the inventory, but that is pretty gritty and couldn't figure out what was crashing my program when I tested it. Ultimately I figured out it was crashing when I tried to access an element of the array. Now I just have this snippet that assumes the first element is empty and tries to "add" the item given to that index in the array:

```
void Hero::AddToInventory(Item *item)
{
    *inventory[0] = item;
}
```

And here is how I called the method in main():

```
int main()
{
    Hero *player = new Hero("Joe");
    Item *primaryWeapon = new Item("Dagger");
    player->AddToInventory(primaryWeapon);
    return 0;
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated; I'm just a little rusty on my dynamic objects and data structures in C++. Thanks in advance!

P.S.
I know this can be done simpler with vectors but I have not learned how to use those yet and would like to stick with the dynamic arrays for now.

Comment: `I know this can be done simpler with vectors but I have not learned how to use those yet`  So why not learn them now?  In good C++ courses, you learn vector's first anyway, and you stay away from pointer madness until you have the experience to know what you're doing.  If your goal is to develop a text game, isn't it more fun to actually concentrate on developing the game?

Comment: Sorry, what exactly is the problem?

Comment: If you use an `std::vector<Item>` then your `AddToInventory` method would be `void Hero::AddToInventory(Item const & item) { inventory.push_back(item); }`. Isn't that easier?

Comment: Also, nowhere did you make the provision of deallocating all of that memory you allocated, thus you have created yourself a haven for memory leaks.

Comment: If you insist on using pointers, I would suggest you develop a dynamic array class first (using templates) that adds, removes, etc.  Then when you have the bugs out of it, use it in your main application.  You not only learn about pointers, you learn about proper resource management, copying issues, templates, etc.

Comment: a dynamic array class... like `std::vector`

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you leak memory by first initializing each array index with a `new Item()` and then replacing that allocated item with the actual item later.  It is probably better to just have an array of null pointers to begin with.

```
Item** inventory = new Item*[15];
for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++)
    inventory[i] = NULL;
```

I believe you can also initialize an array to null like this:

```
Item** inventory = new Item*[15] = {NULL,};
```

Now, you say you have a subclass of `Item` called `Weapon`, but I see that you never use it.  Once you declare `new Item()`, it is of type Item, no longer able to morph into derived class types like `Weapon()`.  So, in this case, to create a dagger weapon, it should look more like this instead:

```
Item *primaryWeapon = new Weapon("Dagger");
```

Lastly, you get the crash during `AddInventoryToItem` because you are dereferencing your instance of `Item` at the given index, then assigning it to a pointer to an `Item` instead of to an `Item` directly.  Try this instead:

```
void Hero::AddToInventory(Item *item)
{
    inventory[0] = item;
}
```

Also note that if you just simply replace the inventory index with a new pointer, you could also result in a memory leak.  However, if each item was initialized to null instead of a `new Item()`, and you only added the item to an empty slot, this won't be a problem.

Comment: Yeah the new Item("Dagger") part was just something I changed when testing it and forgot to change back. The only issue I'm having now is in AddToInventory I can't set an Item** = Item*

Comment: That is because an `Item**` is not an `Item*`... if you really want to preserve the pointer and only assign the `Item` data at the pointer, try this instead `*inventory[0] = *item;`

Comment: That's because you're dereferincing it with *inventory[0]. When you use the * you are now accessing the value there so *inventory[0] is the item at 0, not a pointer to it. Try just copying the value:
 invetory[0]->value = item->value